# Use of mv comand in Linux

Tags: linux, unix, command, mv

I have a bunch of files 
that have different extensions:

```
.png .fa .sh
```

which were in a directory called 'files'.

I wanted to move each

```
.png to images directory
.fa to fasta directory
.sh to upper directory Golden_Asian.git/
```

Moving the .png and .fa files worked well, 
but for the `.sh` file, when I did

```
mv files/*.sh Golden_Asian.git
```

it just made type POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable, with the name

```
Golden_Asian.git
```

the name of the original file was

```
 script.sh
```

so I was supposed to get a result like

```
Golden_Asian.git/script.sh
```

Did I do something wrong or is it the right result?

The original file in the "files" directory has disappeared, so I'm pretty sure 
the file has been transferred to the right directory but don't understand why the name has been changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the right result if there was only one `.sh` file and there was no directory called `Golden_Asian.git` in the current directory.  You executed `mv files/script.sh Golden_Asian.git`, so it moved the file from the original name to the name you specified.   If there was already a file `Golden_Asian.git` in the current directory, it would be clobbered (replaced) by the new file.  If there was a folder named `Golden_Asian.git` in the current directory, you'd have a file `Golden_Asian.git/script.sh` after the command.  That's not what you got, so it is legitimate to deduce that you did not have a folder called `Golden_Asian.git` in the current directory when you executed the command.

If you'd specified:

```
mv *.sh Golden_Asian.git/
```

then it would have required the directory to exist and the result would have been a file `Golden_Asian.git/script.sh`.  If you'd had more than one `.sh` file, then you'd have needed the directory `Golden_Asian.git` to exist.  You said "upper directory"; did you intend to write:

```
mv *.sh ../Golden_Asian.git
```

If there was a directory in the parent directory called `Golden_Asian.git`, then the script would have been moved there.  If there was no directory, the file would have been moved up a level and renamed.  Again, a trailing `/` would have prevented confusion.

Note that moving a file into a GIT directory (especially a [bare repository](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server)) is probably not a good idea.

Comment: oh thanks a lot I'm still bit confused with the concept, but your answer was really helpful !

Comment: Suppose your current directory was `/home/someone`. The file `files/script.sh` existed as `/home/someone/files/script.sh`. Was there a folder `/home/someone/files/Golden_Asian.git` or a folder `/home/someone/Golden_Asian.git`? If `Golden_Asian.git` was in the `/home/someone` directory, then `mv files/*.sh Golden_Asian.git` would have moved the file from `/home/someone/files/script.sh` to `/home/someone/Golden_Asian.git/script.sh`. Since that wasn't the result you got, it is legitimate to deduce that there wasn't already a directory `/home/someone/Golden_Asian.git`. It might've been a file.

Comment: directory was like /home/someone/Golden_Asian.git/files/script.sh

Comment: Then you ended up with a file `/home/someone/Golden_Asian.git/Golden_Asian.git` — you should have done `mv files/*.sh .` or `mv files/*.sh /home/someone/Golden_Asian.git`.  Either would have worked.